# Function returns how many integer elements in a list are exact squares of other elements in the same list

Tags: python

Task:

Write a Python function that returns how many integer elements in a list are exact squares of other elements in the same list. Assume that the list does not contain negative numbers and that there are no duplicates.

This function takes in a list and returns the count. For example, if x is [3,4,0,2,1,9,25] then sum returns 4 because 3*3=9 , 0*0=0 , 1*1=1 , 2*2=4.

Here is my code:

```
x = [3,4,0,2,1,9,25]
def count(x):
    sum = 0
    for i in x:
       if i*i in x is True:
            sum += 1
    return sum
```

When I run count(x) the output is 0 not 4, I think the logic is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The operator `is` is a [comparison operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons), thus when you do `i*i in x is True`, Python interprets it as `i*i in x and x is True`. In that case `x is True` is always false.

Note that you do not explicitly need to compare the value to `True`, since `in` returns a boolean.

```
x = [3,4,0,2,1,9,25]
def count(x):
    sum = 0
    for i in x:
       if i*i in x: # Simply remove 'is True'
            sum += 1
    return sum
```

Although, thes above is *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* due to list lookup. You could use a `set` for constant time lookup and use the fact that `True == 1` and `False == 0` to use `sum` and get an efficient *O(n)* algorithm.

```
def count(x):
    x_set = set(x)
    return sum(i*i in x_set for i in x)
```

Comment: Thanks Olivier, very clear!

Answer (score 1):

`int(True)` returns `1` and `int(False)` returns `0` so why not just use one-line of `sum`:

```
def count(x):
    return sum(i*i in x for i in x)
```

**Demo:**

```
x = [3,4,0,2,1,9,25]
def count(x):
    return sum(i*i in x for i in x)
print(count(x))
```

Output:

```
4
```

Or faster:

```
def count(x):
    return sum([i*i in x for i in x])
```

**Demo:**

```
x = [3,4,0,2,1,9,25]
def count(x):
    return sum([i*i in x for i in x])
print(count(x))
```

Output:

```
4
```

**Summary about why your code doesn't work:**

The issue with your code is that you don't need `is True` at the end of the code otherwise that could also be a solution

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
if i*i in x is True:
```

it actually [chains the conditional operators](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) so that it is equivalent to:

```
i*i in x and x is True:
```

which is not what you're looking for.

You can instead use parentheses to explicitly do:

```
if (i*i in x) is True:
```

and your code would work.

But then you don't really need to compare a Boolean expression to a Boolean value. You can simply instead do:

```
if i*i in x:
```

Comment: That is not why it does not work, it's due to chaining of operators. Do not use == either

Comment: Yes, already corrected it.

Comment: This is still wrong, `i*i in x is True` is interpreted as `i*i in x and x is True`.

Comment: You're right. I've updated my answer accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can just do a *list comprehension* instead of using a creating a function

```
count = len([i for i in x if i*i in x])
```